# What can I plant in dandelion graves?

Tags: weed-control, dandelions

As part of my [other question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4081/verifying-dandelion-extraction-root-and-all), I started uprooting dandelions. How successful, exactly, in removing the root, I'm not sure.

Assuming that I am not always extracting 100% of the root, **what can I put in the dug-up "grave" to prevent or stunt future dandelion growth?** For example, if I put salt, it's not likely the dandelion will grow back -- but neither will anything else! (I plan to eventually grow something.)

So, what can or should I be putting in here? Is grass seed "okay" or "good enough?" Is there something benign that will compete with dandelions?

Chemicals are a no-go -- I have young kids who play in the backyard, and in my area, they just banned a whole slew of lawn chemicals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but I might take a two-pronged approach:

- Squirt a little vinegar down the hole -- maybe 5mL with a child's medicine dropper to get it down in the hole. I don't know if 5mL is enough to really do anything to the dandelion, but it shouldn't be enough to cause collateral damage. IANAL, but I can't imagine that vinegar qualifies as a banned herbicide, and at any rate, it's perfectly safe for kids.
- Then fill in the hole with finely screened compost, smooth the surface, and sprinkle a pinch of grass seed over the top. Keep moist until it germinates.

My hope is that the vinegar would damage any remaining taproot without causing damage to the lawn, the compost will buffer the germinating seed from the vinegar and feed the new grass, and the lawn seed will sprout and grow in thickly before the dandelion gets a chance to regrow.

(After writing the answer above, I found [this article](http://landscaping.about.com/od/weedsdiseases/qt/vinegar_weeds.htm) about battling dandelions with vinegar, so it looks like what I've described above has been done before. About halfway down they mention that the best time for this treatment would be in autumn.)

Answer (score 6):

> **How To Get Rid of Dandelions:** The best way to get rid of dandelions is
>   to remove them by hand. The key is to get all, or as much as possible,
>   of the long taproot, since the plant can regenerate from any root
>   pieces that remain in the soil. Water the area the day before you plan
>   to weed, then use a long, narrow tool, such as a flat screwdriver or
>   dandelion digger. Insert the tool as deeply as you can next to the
>   crown of the dandelion, and wiggle the tool to loosen the soil around
>   the root. Test to see if it is loose by gently tugging on the plant.
>   Once there is little resistance, pull the dandelion out of the soil.
>
> **How To Prevent Dandelions:** Soils with low levels of calcium, and that
>   don't break down organic matter quickly, are havens for dandelions,
>   especially in lawns. If you have a lot of dandelions, top dress your
>   lawn in the fall with compost. This will improve the nutrient level
>   and introduce microbes that will break down organic matter more
>   quickly. In addition, mow your lawn high and use a mulching mower to
>   leave your clippings on the lawn. Try to remove any existing
>   dandelions before they go to seed. For garden beds, a three inch layer
>   of mulch will usually prevent dandelions from popping up.
>   -[http://organicgardening.about.com](http://organicgardening.about.com/od/weeds/p/dandelions.htm)

**But if I could convince you to spare these well-intended yet invasive buggers:**

> The dandelion plant is a beneficial weed, with a wide range of uses,
>   and is even a good companion plant for gardening. Its taproot will
>   bring up nutrients for shallower-rooting plants, and add minerals and
>   nitrogen to soil. It is also known to attract pollinating insects and
>   release ethylene gas which helps fruit to ripen.
>   http://www.countryfarm-lifestyles.com/companion-planting.html

Comment: Nice answer. But, doesn't address my specific question. I don't mind the dandelions themselves, but the leaves are very spiny, and it makes the backyard unusable for playing. Plus, it sucks up nutrients that could go to other plants.

Comment: Let me explain further, when I read "Soils with low levels of calcium, and that don't break down organic matter quickly, are havens for dandelions" I interpreted that as calcium (lime or chalk) will prevent or diminish the growth of dandelions.

Comment: So you're proposing I put *a piece of lime or chalk* in dandelion graves? Seriously? (And if so: how will that affect future growth of anything else?)

Comment: I am suggesting that perhaps twice in one month you spread a light layer of lime or chalk over the entire area you intend to prevent dandelion from growing. Calcium carbonate will help improve the uptake of major nutrients in all plants growing in acidic soil.

Comment: That's going to kill my grass and veggies too, I vager. Will a small dose of it on the "grave" be sufficient?

Comment: Calcium will not kill your grass or veggies. Calcium is a supplement not a weed killer. It would be the same as taking a stimulant to prevent drowsiness.

Comment: @ashes999 are you sure those are dandelions? I've never seen dandelions with spiny leaves. Are they perhaps thistles?

Comment: @DA. I'm sure. They have the characteristic yellow => white flower heads.

Comment: @ashes999 well, it probably doesn't matter, but there are other plants that look like dandelions. Granted, the treatment is probably the same. I just question that they are actually dandelions as I've never seen dandelions with thorny leaves. They can make a lawn look ugly, but never had issues with them and my bare feet. ;) The thistles, on the other hand...

Comment: @DA. I suspect I have both. But anyway, it's a moot point; I trace the yellow head down to the spiny leaves, and then freak out :)

Comment: @ashes999: Can you include a photo of the plants you want to remove? They sure don't sound like dandelion to me, either.

Comment: @Flimzy the other stuff is bull thistle. The dandelions are nothing else (signature yellow flower heads on the classic crown of stems).