# What is the proper method for repairing the holes left behind after pulling dandelions?

Tags: lawn-repair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I plant in dandelion graves?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4082/what-can-i-plant-in-dandelion-graves)

I've been very active this year religiously pulling dandelions with a dedicated weed removal tool and my lawn is virtually free of the "yellow menace" now. When I pulled the dandilions out, a small but noticable hole is left behind. Typically I step on the hole in an effort to close it, but I feel like I should fill it in with soil or something. Can someone recommend a good solution to fill the many holes on my nice green lawn?

Comment: Just wondering what this "dedicated weed removal tool" is

Comment: Probably this: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/outdoor-living/detailpages/fiskars/B0030MIHAU-A.jpg

Comment: zk and chris.....yes thats close to the one I have, just less fancy.

Answer (score 6):

Leave the holes: they'll help to aerate your lawn just as well as any man-made hole.

If you have circular patches where the rosette of dandelion leaves has killed the grass, loosen the top inch or so of soil with a handheld cultivator, mix some grass seed into some compost and scatter it over the missing patch. Then keep it well watered for a few weeks until the grass is established.

Comment: zk and Chris, yes my weed removal tool is very similar (tsc about 22.99 about 4 years ago). I was thinking about topsoil, with a little fertilizer and then sprinkling some grass seed on top.

Comment: @RobInCanada: topsoil would work too, but mix the seed into it so that it's not lying on top where it would dry out quickly between waterings or get washed away if you get heavy rain.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect either dirt or patience will do the trick... I just paid someone 30 bucks to put a whole bunch of holes in my lawn...